# Reversing string variables, or printing an array of char in reverse

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf, scanf

So I have been looking and trying to find an easy fix to this problem that does not involve a solution with the "cin", "cout" thing that is pretty common in c++. What I am trying to accomplish is scanning an entry from the keyboard and then printing it in reverse order. I think something is wrong with my syntax, but I do not know what the problem is.

The output I get after using "abc" as my input 5 times is this:

```
//Start of input
Enter a string:
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc
╠
cba
cba
cba
cba
cb
Enter a string:
//End of output
```

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define SIZE 20

int main()
{
    char a[SIZE];
    int i, j, k = 0, pass;
    char hold = ' ';

    for (i = 1; i != 0; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a string: \n");

        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            scanf_s("%c", &a[i]);
            k++;
        }

        for (j = k; j > 0; j--)
        {
            printf("%c", a[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're not using `cin` and `cout` then you're not writing in idiomatic C++ - what you have is closer to C.

Comment: You're asking for an easy solution but refusing to use the easy solution (`std::string` and `std::cin`). Please explain why you wish to avoid reading input from `cin` into a `string` then reversing it using builtin libraries? Do you feel this is something you will need to do lots of , or you'll have a job that doesn't allow use of the standard libraries?

Comment: Is there a reason for the C++ tag rather than C? What is the reason for not using C++ libraries?

Comment: @Dai Understood  i will make changes accordingly.

Comment: @JiveDadson my apologies. I am new to this so i will explain my professors stipulations next time. I didn't mean to cause any confusion

Comment: @Tas my professor does not allow us to use those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
 for (j = k; j > 0; j--)
    {
        printf("%c", a[j]);
    }
```

have a problem
why don't you iterate a[0]?

look, this is your input

```
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%c", &a[i]);
        k++;
    }
```

You've reserved a character in a[0], so of course you should print it, like:

```
for (j = k; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        printf("%c", a[j]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No comment on why are you actually are using C++ compiler for this.

To your problem, you shall count down to 0 to move trough whole `a`.

```
for (j = k; j >= 0; j--) {
    printf("%c", a[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you the logic. But array is the easy way to declare and do so. or when you do loop, declare it reverse. Hope it helps you think the possible answer.

```
for (int a= b; a>= 0; j--){
   //statement here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it would be done this way:

```
    std::string inp;
    std::cin >> inp;
    for (auto it = inp.rbegin(); it != inp.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
```

If you want an answer that involves no C++, change the tag from C++ to C.